# MYSQL SELECT and JSON_ENCODE

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need to select a key from a json_encodED array from mysql..

```
SELECT * FROM json_field_table WHERE {var from JSON encoded array} = {expected value}
```

or something..
How I can do this?

*PS.: Poor English, I know..*

Comment: Regardless of your language knowledge, you should really, really take more time to make an actual question. It'S way too unspecific to answer it.

Comment: Well I think that's an answerable question. But only with: **no**. If you have a JSON encoded structure in your database table, you will first have to transfer it to the application to unpack and compare an entry of that array. MySQL provides no built-in functions to deal with JSON (it does for XML), and it's unlikely anyone has crafted a stored procedure for that yet. (Well, string searching is a workaround.)

Comment: @hakre sorry, I`m Brasiliam and don`t know how to create an question.. is complex to me.

Comment: @mario Select all from DB then decode json field, and check?

Comment: @Gabriel: Yes, that would be the \*correct\* approach. But that is obviously not a \*workable\* solution due to the overhead.

Comment: As @Marc B commented, using regular expression ia  a good idea so far..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to use substring matching. MySQL doesn't have anything to deal with JSON data and treats it like it does any other piece of random text.

```
SELECT ... WHERE the_json_field LIKE '%"var":"value"%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Gabriel, despite the nature of your question. I am supposing, your problem might be, you need to read a JSON value and based on that values, you need to retrieve the record set from the table. If this is the case, here is your solution.

```
// A sample json string
$json = '{ "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2" }'; 

// Here we will convert the json string into readable assocative array
$json_array = json_decode($json,true); 

//Next we will use it on a query
$query = "SELECT * json_field_table WHERE `".$json_array['field1']."` = 'Some Value' ";

//Execute the query
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Can't you retrieve the row and then check it later on. What you are trying to do, will create a very inefficient solution. There might be better way to do, what you are trying to do. But, if you insist on going with your idea, then better go with @Marc B's solution.

Answer (score 0):

with numbers (integers) you can filter out values, with alphanumeric strings is more complicated as the value stored is "jsonencoded"

check my answer to [17955206](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138001/how-to-search-a-json-encoded-value-in-a-mysql-field/17955206#17955206)