# How to search a json encoded value in a mysql column?

Tags: mysql, json, search

I have stored some extra form data as json in a mysql column (`extraData`).

Example data

```
{"1":{"name":"sadsdaf ","surname":"sdafa","occupation":"sdaas","email":"dsasdaf@asdf.nl","barcode":"052355491"},"2":{"name":"sadafd","surname":"sdafa","occupation":"sddaf","email":"sda@daf.nl","barcode":"052355492"}}
```

I would like to do a search query which also does a search for the barcode stored in the json encoded field? So not only this

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM visitors WHERE barcode = '".$barcode."'";
```

But also

```
 $sql = "SELECT name FROM visitors WHERE barcode = '".$barcode."' OR extraData = '".$barcode."'";
```

What do I need to do to `extraData` so the variable barcode is checked and I get the corresponding name, surname etc?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(V.extraData,'"name":', -1),',',1),'}',1) 
 FROM visitors V
 WHERE  V.extraData LIKE '%"barcode"%'
   AND :barcode = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(V.extraData,'"barcode":', -1),',',1),'}',1);
```

the **LIKE '%"barcode"%'** filters the rows with the field extraData containing barcode values
the **:barcode** means to be the value to match, the TRIM is to get rid of the extra double quotes , the nested SUBSTRING_INDEX searchs for:

> the text starting at the end of the first match of '"barcode":' up to
>   the next match of ',' (if there are more key/values) up to the next
>   match of '}' (if it's the last key/value at that level)

1. keep in mind that if you find that a certain key/val is always present in every row and is accessed everywhere you should consider adding an extra field to the table/data model and create an index out of it (ie. name, surname).
2. the values retrieved must be decoded "always".

   ```
   "Einstürzende Neubauten" is stored as "Einst\u00fcrzende Neubauten"
   ```
3. doing search and compare numbers are "ok", like in the example (the trim double quotes sometimes would not be necesary as if you json_encode an integer var it will be stored as "number":99 ). but fractional numbers would be stored depending on the locale "1,5" / "1.5"
4. search and compare strings are more tricky: you have to "jsonencode" the value to match

   ```
   "https://www.google.com" is stored as "https:\/\/www.google.com"
   ```
5. check your [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) skills.
6. check your [optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html) skills
7. use [an online tool](http://www.functions-online.com/json_encode.html) to see how your data will be encoded

Comment: Is it considered bad form to upvote a post simply because it incldes "Einstürzende Neubauten" as an example?

Comment: @lysdexia yes it is

Comment: @Andrew glad I kept control of myself, then.